# How to dynamically get cell value in a Filter Match formula in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm using this formula in the header cell to apply it to the entire column at once.

```
ArrayFormula(IF(ROW(B:B)=1,"HEADER", IF(ISBLANK(B:B) = True, "", FILTER('SHEET1'!$G$150:$G,'SHEET1'!$D$150:$D = B2))))
```

The final value B2 is matched with the columns in sheet1 to get the desired result. I want this value to update according to the cell number. Right now it only compares B2, but I want it to compare B3, B4 and so on but with only one formula in the header cell. I can drag the formula across the column to get the desired results but I don't want to do that as it causes other issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See if this works?

```
= {"HEADER";  INDEX(IF(LEN(B2:B), IFERROR(VLOOKUP(B2:B, {SHEET1!$D$150:$D,SHEET1!$G$150:$G}, 2, 0)),))}
```

Comment: This worked flawlessly. I'm quite new to these formulas and still learning. I'm going to look more into Vlookup to understand how this works. Thank you so much for this. I really appreciate it.